# Setting my compiled .scss file to output to the root folder in config.rb

Tags: css, ruby, compass-sass

I am trying to set my css output file from the config.rb file to the root level of my main directory and to be named "style.css". The issue I am having is I when I set all of the filepaths in the config.rb like the following it all works fine.

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "assets/css"
sass_dir = "assets/sass"
images_dir = "assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "assets/js"
fonts_dir = "assets/fonts"
output_style = :compressed
environment = :development
```

**But** I develop a lot of WordPress websites locally and need to have the `css_dir = "assets/css"` be set to the root of the main directory and to be named style.css. if I try things like`css_dir = "/"` it breaks and doesn't output my `style.css` to the root.

Any suggestions please as to how I may do this so  I don't have to stick with the current way of moving my output from assets/css/style.css to the root level manually upon deployment, (this has been my previous solution). This would not be ground breaking in my efficiency or my workflow, but it seems so simple and that it should be an option, so I have to ask the community.

I also tried Chris Coyier's suggestion here and that didn't seem to work either http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

When setting your `http_path` in `config.rb`, you are telling Compass what the path to the current directory is. It's only really used if you have absolute paths turned on and are using Compass URL helpers. Compass doesn't know what your "real" project root is (when it comes to PHP CMSes like WordPress or Drupal, for example).

Let's take the following document structure:

```
project_root
- foo
-- bar
--- baz
```

`baz` is going to be our theme folder.

Now when it comes to compiling your CSS, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, whether it's that you want to change the CSS Directory for your production build only and keep it at `assets/css` for your development, or just change the directory. Either way, I've got you covered. For both of these, we're going to assume that the outside of Compass root directory we want the CSS generated in is `project_root`

**Change CSS Directory Path for Production Build Only**

Set `css_dir = (environment == :development) ? 'assets/css' : '../../../'` to compile your CSS into `assets/css` during development builds (`compass compile`/`compass watch`) and into `project_root` during production builds (`compass compile -e production --force`). The key here is that we're using Unix style directory changing to place the file outside of our theme directory.

**Change CSS Directory Path for All Compiling**

Set `css_dir = "../../../" and simply run`compass watch`/`compass compile` as normal.

Either way, don't have Compass rewrite your file name. Name your Sass file `style.scss`